# Detecting if textarea value is modified

Tags: javascript, html

I want to detect if textarea value is modified.
here is whatever I've done-
html:

```
<textarea id="textarea" autofocus></textarea>
```

js:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
textarea.onpaste = textarea.onkeypress = function() { 
  isModified = true;
};
```

I know there is another option, `onchange` but that won't work here because the `textarea` is `autofocus`ed and the `onchange` event wont work until the `textarea` is blured. and I don't want to blur the textarea.

So my question is that are there any other option of doing so?
Thanks.

Comment: `onkeyup` event can do the job.

Comment: The event handler can be unsubscribed on first run. This would remove the overhead of triggering for every click.

Comment: If you don't need it in real-time (each letter as they type), you can use onfocus and record the value with a setInterval() set to like 2 or 3 seconds, depending on your end goal.

Answer (score -4):

Check the Javascript on this page (something that I built loooong ago), it might help you. :)
http://www.frofens.org/myvirtualnotepad/demo/

Comment: Please add relevant code into the answer to avoid dead links instead of just linking to your website. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: Didn't find anything about using links in the the link you provided. And it's not my website, just a script. I don't have a website. Was just trying to help.

Comment: The list on the page I linked states that "barely more than a link to an external site" is a reason for deletion.

Comment: Ok, point taken. Won't happen again.